# the_content(); doesn't print anything in my wordpress custom template page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to show 2 articles in a custom template page in my wordpress blog, but this code show nothing.

```
  $myposts = get_posts("numberposts=2&category=3"); 
foreach($myposts as $post) : the_content(); endforeach;
```

but if I try to `print_r($myposts);` I can say that there is an array..how can i solve this problem?
thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think this is how `the_content()` works. Try `get_the_content()` (no guarantees though, these functions are usually available only in The Loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya need to use [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)!

```
query_posts("numberposts=2&category=3");
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 6):

Write this line:

```
the_post();
```

before you use:

```
the_content();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this:-

```
    <ul>
     <?php
     global $post;
     $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=1&category=1');
     foreach($myposts as $post) :
       setup_postdata($post);
     ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php the_content() ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
```

may helpful http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
Thanks.